# I am starting a latin language journal. Would it be appropriate to ask questions about my entries?

Tags: discussion

To try and improve my Latin language skills, I am starting a journal in Latin. My goal is write a few sentences every day.

Would it be on-topic to post my Latin entries at Latin.StackExchange.com, along with my intended meaning (in English) to solicit feedback for improving the Latin sentences?

Comment: In addition to what cmw wrote: Maybe you can try the [r/latin](https://www.reddit.com/r/latin) forum on Reddit; it does not adhere to the strict question-and-answer format that you find here, and is much more in the style of a free conversation. It is my impression that it very much welcomes people "trying out" their Latin, and you are likely to get some answers. It is, of course, Reddit …

Answer (score 6):

This isn't official policy, but I'll chime in with my 2c on what I think.

First, welcome to Latin! I do hope you stick around. In general, "proofread my translation"-type questions are not good candidates for questions here. But, if there is something specific about a translation you have done, then you're of course welcome to post that. Posts here work best when they're tightly woven around a central question. A "check my work" question though can cover many different possibilities.

So, if you're uncertain about a grammatical construction that you're trying out for the first time, and the other questions here don't fully answer what you're looking at, then that's a fine question.

Or if you're unsure of how to express a certain idiom in Latin, then by all means, post as much of that idiom as you can. Or if you're looking for style pointers, ask specifically on that.

You get the idea.

The other issue is that repeatedly asking about the same thing for many subsequent days can look like spamming. Even worse than breaking a rule, that can aggravate the users! And questions that are almost identical risk being closed as duplicates.

If you want feedback on your daily material, it might be best to ask in the chatroom and save the questions on the main site for particular questions that arise as you're translating.

Comment: I see lots of chat rooms. Should I start my own for feedback on my journal entries or would it fit in an existing one? I looked and couldn't find one that seemed a good fit to use for my purposes.

Comment: And thank you for the feedback!

Comment: @Josh: You could just post in the common room, Colloquium. People might or might not respond, but a post e.g. once a day would probably be welcomed!

Comment: And you'll probably get more interaction than creating a new one.